# How to chain in cascade two VPNs on macOS?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard, ipsec

Given the following VPNs:

- a WireGuard VPN I've created with a Fritz!Box
- a Cisco IPSec VPN

I'd like to know if it's possible to connect to the Cisco VPN using the IP obtained via the WireGuard VPN. It should be something possible because in the past I've managed (by accident) to connect to my office VPN using the IP given by the NordVPN client that was running in my MacBook.

Does anybody know how to achieve it? One solution I've thought is to set the WireGuard VPN at router level, but it would have two downsides:

1. it works only when connected to that specific router
2. it forces me to redirect all the Internet traffic through the WireGuard VPN

I'm open to any kind of alternative solution if my proposal doesn't make any sense or it's not achievable.